# com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character

Tags: web-services, weblogic, axis, stax

I am running the below exception when processing an Axis 2 web service in Client Stub. The issue happens only on WebLogic Server. The services (aar files) work fine in development on Tomcat Server but throws the below error in production on WebLogic Server. Services were built using Axis 2.0 Version 1.6.2.  I am not sure why they work fine on Tomcat but has issues when run on WebLogic Version 10.3.5. This used to work fine with Axis 2.0 V 1.4.

Exception on myClientClass.java:

`org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ':' (code 58) excepted space, or '>' or "/>"  at javax.xml.stream.SerializableLocation@89d089d`

I see the below warning on WebLogic startup log.

`[WARN] Weblogic's StAX implementation is unsupported and some Axiom features will not work as expected! Please use Woodstox instead.`

I found some references online that I need to use Woodstox. So, I added the below to `webLogicStart.sh`

```
-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory
-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory
-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxEventFactory
```

and the below to stubClass before invoking the web service.

```
          _operationClient.getOptions().setProperty("javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory",   
                  "com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory");   
          _operationClient.getOptions().setProperty("javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory",   
                  "com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory");   
          _operationClient.getOptions().setProperty("javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory",   
                  "com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxEventFactory");
```

And the below to weblogic-application.xml.

```
    <wls:package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>javax.xml.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.apache.*</wls:package-name>
```

I still get the same issue. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does anyone know if Axis2 1.6.2 is broken on WebLogic 10.3.5? How can I force WebLogic to use Woodstox XML processor?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error.
I created axis client with wsdl2java.
Check your jdk compile and runtime version, they have to be the same.
I solved it using both with 1.5 and javaee5.0.
Also check any dependencies with axis2 at www.findjar.com.

Hope it helps

Luca